# kmllayer overlay markers?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

pardon the noob question but...
i am adding a kml layer to my gmap.  the kml is on my webserver and is being fetched ny google map.  i get the default blue icon.  so far so good, however  i want a custon marker and ultimately the ability to change the style based o a event later.  everything point to this method

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(56.8848, 14.7730), 
  map: map,
  title: 'My workplace',
  clickable: false,
  icon: 'http://google-maps-icons.googlecode.com/files/factory.png'
});
```

it seems to me that this only controls the marker defined by the LatLng. in other words only a single point.

how do i define a custom marker for all of my sites within the kml layer.  heres the link to my map

http://myfloridagps.com/SpiderWeb/KML/map.html

the one green icon i change within the kml directly and seems to limit any future functionality.

Comment: Do you want all the icons to be the same?  Or different for each marker?  KML allows you to define shared styles that can be used on multiple Placemarks.  If you need to change styles based on events, you may want to look at FusionTablesLayer (FusionTables can import KML), or using a third party KML parser like [geoxml3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) or [geoxml-v3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/), which render the KML using native Google Maps API v3 objects.

Comment: eventually yes.  i want the site to be independently controlable.  whati need is the marker for each site to be green by default.  based on an event in a  log file from my data acquisition server, each site that tracks and fixes less than 4 satellites should post as red.  this log file updates at a 10 minute cycle and is in xml format.  at this point i am working thru the basics to build my understanding of the programming involved and am stumped on how to change the standard blue marker..

Answer (score 0):

Specify an icon style:

```
<Style id="mm_orange_hd2">
  <IconStyle>
    <Icon>
      <href>http://missouristate.info/images/2010/homecoming/mm_orange.png</href>
    </Icon>
    <hotSpot x="20" y="2" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels"/>
  </IconStyle>
</Style>
```

Reference said style:

```
<Placemark id="id1">
  <name>Crosstown Barbeque</name>
  <styleUrl>#mm_orange_hd2</styleUrl>
  <Point>
    <coordinates>-93.272,37.2278,0</coordinates>
  </Point>
</Placemark>
```

[See a full example](http://missouristate.info/map/homecoming/2012/mapmarkers.aspx?category=eat_casual)

Keep in mind that you will have to append random data to your kml file url to prevent the maps servers from caching it.